# Python: Inserting sublist into main list is replacing all the existing sublist

Tags: python, list, printing, insert, logic

I have the below python code where an insert a sublist tmp[] into the main list lis[]. Every time, I add the sublist to the main list, all the list elements in the main list get replaced by the sublist

```
tmp = [0]  
lis = []
tmp[0] = 0
lis.insert(0,tmp)
print lis
tmp[0] = 1
lis.insert(1,tmp)
print lis
```

Output:

```
[[0]]
[[1], [1]]
```

What change should I make to get output like below

```
[[0]]
[[0], [1]]
```

Comment: You're inserting the same variable tmp so the reference is the same, use a different variable

Answer (score 0):

The technical issue is that lists are *mutable*, which means that you are actually inserting the same object twice instead of inserting two distinct objects. Changes to `tmp` are reflected in both places that you see it, the 0th and 1st entries of `lis`. There isn't a great way to get around this without making a new variable or overwriting the old name.

```py
>>> tmp = [0]  
>>> lis = []
>>> tmp[0] = 0
>>> lis.insert(0,tmp)
>>> print(lis)
[[0]]

>>> tmp2 = [1]
>>> lis.insert(1,tmp2)
>>> print(lis)
[[0], [1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it:

```
lis = []
tmp = [0]
lis.insert(0,tmp)
print(lis)
tmp = [1]
lis.insert(1,tmp)
print(lis)
```

Output:

```
[[0]]
[[0], [1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This behavior in Python occurs because [lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) in Python are [mutable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-mutable).

**According to the Python documentation:**

> Mutable objects can change their value but keep their id().

So essentially when you insert the list `tmp` into `lis` at index 0, `tmp is lis[0]` evaluates to `True` and `id(tmp) == id(lis[0])` also evaluates to `True`. Then when you later change the element at index 0 of the list `tmp` from 0 to 1, because mutable objects "change their value but keep their id()", both `tmp is lis[0]` and `id(tmp) == id(lis[0])` still evaluate to `True`. So therefore inserting `tmp[0]` into `lis[1]` results in duplicate elements at `lis[0]` and `lis[1]`.

**Solution**

To mitigate this instead of using lists we can use an immutable object (as you'd expect immutable objects change their value but lose their id()) such as [tuples](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences). But of course tuples have limitations too, because tuples are immutable we cannot modify their contents after they have been initialized (through insert, remove etc.). Tuples in Python are notated the same as lists except instead of initializing them with `[]` (or square brackets) we use `()`.

*For example* a solution (using tuples) to your example problem would be:

```
tmp = (0,)  # In order to initialize a tuple a comma is always required after the first element
lis = []
lis.insert(0, tmp)
print(lis)
tmp = (1,)  # We cannot modify tuples therefore we must create a new one.
lis.insert(1, tmp)
print(lis)
```